# overflow-y:visible in combination with overflow-x:hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

i am trying to design form with multiple steps where the next step will slide-in by bootstrap's carousel:

[image]

The problem ist that the carousel has an overflow definition which would cut off the chosen select options (not cuted in picture):

[image]

It seems that `overflow-y:visible` to allow the select options to be shown and `overflow-x:hide` to prevent the elements being visible outside of the container when sliding does not really work together. Even disabling overflow hiding of the carousel and only clipping horizontal overflow at the `#wrapper` does not work. Is there some way to have clipping for the x-axis but not for the y-axis?

Here's a complete not-working fiddle to show and experiment with the problem:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.carousel .item').removeClass('active');
  $('.carousel #item-select').addClass('active');
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
  });

  $('select').chosen();

  $('a#toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel('next')
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

#wrapper {
  /* enabling will somehow change overflow-y too? */
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

.carousel-inner {
  /* disables overflow definition of carousel */
  overflow: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" style="margin:50px;">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div id="item-select" class="item">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
          <label for="someselect">Some Select:</label>
          <select id="someselect" class="form-control">
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
                <option>option3</option>
                <option>option4</option>
                <option>option5</option>
                <option>option6</option>
         </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="item-other" class="item">some other</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="toggle" class="btn btn-primary">toggle content</a>
```

Comment: @Pete, I think he has different problem here.

Comment: @Afsar same problem - the combination of hidden and visible in any combination